# Preserve a value across component redraw

Tags: ember.js

I have a component something like this

```
Ember.Component.extends({
    text : null,
});
```

Due to some external events the component redraws after sometime.

If user is entering something into `text` value and component redraws the `text` become null again.

Is there a way I can preserve `text` for next redraw so I can reuse it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the value used in component, you can define value at controller level and pass it to component while using it. This way you can retain the value and reuse it in component.

component/message.js

```
Ember.Component.extends({
    text : Ember.computed.alias('messageText'),
});
```

use component as

```
{{message messageText=text}}
```

Hope this help you! Let me know if you have any doubts.